# how to hide ribbon in _layouts\upload.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, file-upload, image-upload

I created a copy of _layouts\upload.aspx and to that copy file..i want to hide the ribbon section when i am trying to upload any files to document library. 
I don't want the entire edit section.(which has all the save,cancel,paste,cut,copy and delete links)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a little CSS. In your copy of the upload.aspx, add a content editor web part to the bottom of the page and add the following CSS snippet. You might want to play with it by removing and re-adding each line to get exactly what you want.

This snippet will strip out a lot, it will only leave the title and the buttons, and will work on a pop-up modal dialog. If you are not using a modal dialog remove the "html.ms-dialog" from all of the lines.

```
<style>
 html.ms-dialog #s4-ribbonrow, 
 html.ms-dialog .ms-cui-topBar2, 
 html.ms-dialog .s4-notdlg, 
 html.ms-dialog .s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle, 
 html.ms-dialog .s4-notdlg noindex, 
 html.ms-dialog .ms-descriptiontext,
 html.ms-dialog #ms-cui-ribbonTopBars, 
 html.ms-dialog #s4-titlerow, 
 html.ms-dialog #s4-pr s4-notdlg s4-titlerowhidetitle, 
 html.ms-dialog #s4-leftpanel-content {
  display:none !important;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add class="s4-notdlg" in the ribbon div in the master page. And open the Ipload.apsx in the popup. The above mention class will prevent to open ribbon in the popup.
It will hide the ribbon in the upload.aspx in the popup. 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eee64d30-6bcc-4287-b883-a9319a85c799/editting-css-classs4pr-s4notdlg?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: But doesn't this will remove the Ribbon from each and every pop-up / modal dialog ?